# How to access attributes of an association directly with an alias/shortcut method, in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have a devise `User` model with just `email` and `password`, but every user `has_one` `Profile` with things like `name`, `username`, etc.

I can reference the profile attributes by going the `user.profile.name` route, but how can I be able to do stuff like `user.name` to access `user.profile.name` directly? I tried a few *self* methods in the `User` class but couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `.delegate` method.

> **delegate**(*methods)
>
> Provides a delegate class method to easily
>   expose contained objects’ public methods as your own.
>
> The macro receives one or more method names (specified as symbols or
>   strings) and the name of the target object via the :to option (also a
>   symbol or string).

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate

Comment: That's perfect, it even has a Profile delegation example in there. Thanks!

Comment: is it possible to .delegate all defined methods instead of naming them one by one?